# netstat for AIX 6.1

Tags: unix, networking, aix

is there a way to grep for network status based on pid on an AIX Box?

I'd like to know if there is a reasonable equivalent of this command below

```
netstat -anp | grep 2767
tcp        0      0 :::47801                    :::*                        LISTEN      2767/java
tcp        0      0 :::33830                    :::*                        LISTEN      2767/java
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      2767/java
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      2767/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:15.213.27.40:60373   ::ffff:15.213.27.21:22      ESTABLISHED 2767/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:15.213.27.40:35040   ::ffff:15.213.27.99:22      ESTABLISHED 2767/java
```

2767 being the processId

Comment: There are very few AIX readers on this forum. http://ittoolbox.com has a forum for AIX that is active and helpful, but the best place to ask AIX questions is on the IBM community/support website. Good luck.

Comment: How about `lsof -n -P -p2767 | grep IPv` ?